# Concurrent inference with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Looking at the cuda backend for tensorflow, it looks like the computation is synchronized on a single cuda stream (which I think makes sense).

This suggests that one could concurrently run inference on two different tensorflow models, sharing the same gpu.  They would each have their own cuda stream and execute independently.

Is this in fact a supported use case?  In particular, I'm curious if (1) this is expected to work and (2) if there are any performance concerns.

Obviously the latency may be a little higher if two models are sharing the same compute resources, but I'm curious if there are any assumptions in tensorflow that would cause more significant performance penalties.

Thanks!